# How to loop through directory and move like files?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a a directory for each day over the course of a year holding certain files about each day. I want to take one file ...mobile_events_... from each day directory and combine all files in one directory titled "MobileEvents". All files and directories are in my Downloads directory (current working directory), "MobileEvents" destination is on the desktop.

I tried a for loop and while loop but the code just keeps running.

for loop

```
for *_mobile_events_201* in 201_*; do mv ~/MobileEvents
```

I am only getting a stall in the program and nothing is being moved. I get a new blank line with '>'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax for a `for` loop is invalid. A correct `for` loop in bash would look like this:

```
for file in *_mobile_events_201*; do mv "$file" ~/MobileEvents; done
```

---

An even better solution would be to use a glob as an argument to `mv` directly:

```
mv *_mobile_events_201* ~/MobileEvents
```

Resources:

- [Loops for, while and until - BASH Programming](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html)